# I am getting variables with bundle but its not updating

Tags: android, bundle

im trying to develop a pedometer. I got steps with sensor but ı need send them to fragment. For that ı used a bundle. Steps variable is passing to fragment but its only getting first value. That first value is zero and i gave that value when i create  variable. This value is updating ım seeing that on stepsTextview. But in bundle not. How can ı get updated variables when sensor changed?

Activity Code:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    if (sensorEvent.sensor == stepCounter){
        stepCount = (int) sensorEvent.values[0];
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(stepCount));
        CountStepFragment fragment = new CountStepFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("Adım", stepCount);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    }

}
```

Fragment Code:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        myInt = bundle.getInt("Adım",0);
        Log.i("sda",String.valueOf(myInt));

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you're doing here is passing that variable ***one time***

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("Adım", stepCount);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

this only happens when you ***create the fragment***

in order to achieve this in your fragment, you'll have to find a way to implement this code inside the actual fragment :

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    if (sensorEvent.sensor == stepCounter){
        stepCount = (int) sensorEvent.values[0];
        //now use stepCount to update your fragment
    }

}
```